# Why class name is same as class used in import statement

Tags: java

Below snippet of code is from ITDIAgentException.java file

Can some one help me understand "why class name is same as class used in import statement"(ITDIAgentException)

```
import com.ibm.di.entry.Entry;
import com.ibm.di.exception.ITDIAgentException;

public class ITDIAgentException extends Exception {
  private Entry entry = null;
  
  public ITDIAgentException(String paramString) { super(paramString); }
  
  public Entry getEntry() { return this.entry; }
  
  public void setEntry(Entry paramEntry) { this.entry = paramEntry; }
}
```

---

EDIT

[image]

Comment: Because Java has defined that a public class needs to be defined in a file with the name of the class + ".java"

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the `package` statement in your class declaration.

Comment: Because for some reason your code is defining a class with the same name as the class that is imported. The import actually does nothing in this case, as the local scope overrides it, so if your code wanted to refer to the imported class it would have to use the fully-qualified class name as in the import statement. Or else the class is importing itself, which is nonsense. Don't write code like this, and don't reuse class names.

Answer (score 0):

You have ITDIAgentException twice: Once in the import statement, and once in the class definition. You are not allowed to have both (would create a namespace clash in the code), but you can access com.ibm.di.exception.ITDIAgentException (assuming that it is different from the class you are creating) by using the full package and class name.

```
import com.ibm.di.exception.ITDIAgentException;

public class ITDIAgentException extends Exception {
```

Comment: If I write a new class "SDIException.java" in following package com.ibm.di.exception
why would I used import com.ibm.di.exception.SDIException.java;
Isn't the SDIException.java file already placed in following hierarchical directory structure "com.ibm.di.exception" ?

Comment: @Mihir It is placed in whatever package it is declared in, which you haven't stated.